# Is canvas load event occurring after other events expected?

Tags: c#, wpf, events, canvas, loaded

It's not clear to me what the order of events are when subscribing to events in xaml. I'm not sure why, but my `canvas1_SizeChanged`event occurs first, and causes a null reference exception because `image` has not yet been initialized because the Loaded event has not happened yet. I'll probably end up just moving the `canvas1_SizeChanged` event subscription to the Loaded handler, however, I'm still curious why the timing is the way it is. Below is a code snippet display my issue.

In xaml:

```
<Canvas Name="canvas1" Loaded="canvas1_Loaded" SizeChanged="canvas1_SizeChanged">
```

in xaml.cs:

```
 private Image image;
 private void canvas1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     image = new Image();
 }

 private void canvas1_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
 {
      content = image.Content;
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal paradigm is this:

1. Call control constructor.
2. Set up control properties (Location, Size, EventHandlers etc)
3. Add Control to parent (if not parent control itself)
4. Show parent

It is at step 2. that you would be getting the call to `canvas1_SizeChanged` event handler.

It is only after step 4. that eh `canvas_Loaded` event handler is called

Comment: So the two options are to have my Eventhandlers check IsLoaded before executing any of its logic. Or to subscribe to the events within the Loaded event. Are there any other reasonable alternatives?